# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.distributed._shard'

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm running some python code that uses the pytorch Lightning framework. I get the error

> File "/Home/LightningVersion.py", line 45, in **init**
> super().**init**()
> File "/Home/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 128, in **init**
> self._register_sharded_tensor_state_dict_hooks_if_available()
> File "/Home/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 1570, in _register_sharded_tensor_state_dict_hooks_if_available
> from torch.distributed._shard.sharded_tensor import pre_load_state_dict_hook, state_dict_hook
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.distributed._shard'

I am using CUDA 11.4 and python 3.9.10.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I cannot find anything online that helps, despite searching.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same error and can't seem to figure it out anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This module is responsible for sharding tensors across multiple GPUs, and it is available in PyTorch versions 1.8 and higher. upgrade your PyTorch version to 1.8 or higher by running

```
!pip install torch==1.8.0
```